# CSS inheritance : ul style not applied to nested div

Tags: html, css

I ran into a problem trying to build a dropdown menu in a navbar, using nested lists.

Here's a snippet of the code :

```css
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover + .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1
}
```

```html
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" data-600='opacity:0' data-1000='opacity:1'>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul id=navbar class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown"><a href=index.html>Jeux de vilains ▼</a></li>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class=secondary><a href=/carto2016-jeuxvideos/article-1.html>Tomb Raider</a></li>
              <li class=secondary><a href=/carto2016-jeuxvideos/article-2.html>GTA</a></li>
              <li class=secondary><a href=/carto2016-jeuxvideos/article-3.html>SimCity</a></li>
              <li class=secondary><a href=/carto2016-jeuxvideos/article-4.html>Call of Duty</a></li>
              <li class=secondary><a href=/carto2016-jeuxvideos/article-5.html>Resident Evil 5</a></li>
              <li class=secondary><a href=/carto2016-jeuxvideos/article-6.html>Civilization</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          </ul>
          </div>
```

**This part was solved :**

> Basically, my problem is that I want my "dropdown" div to have no
>   style of its own, but to inherit the style of the navbar.
>
> The weird thing is that the nested navbar is properly styled, but the
>   dropdown div follows the style of general a and hover:a elements.
>
> If you look at the beginning of my HTML, you'll see the culprit: `<div
>   class="dropdown">`, which appears completely differently from the
>   rest. I don't understand why the class in which it is nested (the nav
>   class) is not considered the parent, especially since the following
>   list is properly styled.
>
> I attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR8JN.png) of what it looks like: "Jeux de vilains"
>   looks weird, when it should look like "Règles du jeu".

**This has been solved too**

> Well thank you all for you swift and kind help, I took out the
>   unwanted div and put the dropdown class in the corresponding li.
>
> However, while the list does appear on hover, it disappears as soon as
>   the mouse is not hovered. I'd like to make it so the secondary menu
>   appears as long as either the parent li or the secondary menu itself
>   are hovered. How could I do that ?
>
> Here's the website :
>   http://medialab.github.io/carto2016-jeuxvideos/index.html
>
> Thanks in advance for everyone's help.

**Question solved.**

Comment: What is `.dropdown {} .dropdown a` supposed to be?

Comment: You appear to be using Bootstrap, if the Bootstrap stylesheets happen to be loading after your custom ones they'll be over-riding any CSS you're trying to change.

Comment: @Midas sorry, it's a leftover of something I tried to fix this. It's supposed to style the "dropdown" div but it doesn't work, I still get the style from a and a:hover.

I can't understand why the style from a and a:hover overrides everything even though the "dropdown" div is nested in the "navbar" div where everything else is styled properly!

Comment: @JackHasaKeyBoard Alright, how could I reverse this order?

Thank you both for your help.

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/ — You can't have a div there. Write valid HTML before trying to style it.

Comment: @Quentin But then how can I build the dropdown part ? Don't you need a "dropdown" div for it to work?

Thanks for the link, I'm looking at all the errors.

Comment: @AlvaroToloza You don't need the `div` per se. You can style the `ul` in itself. See the example here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: Firstly, this is not valid HTML (can't have `div` inside `ul`), like another comment has said. Secondly, if you want the nested `li` to look like a regular `li`, you should show the CSS for your `li`.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, I solved that first issue. However, I have a hard time making it so that when I hover over the secondary menu it remains displayed. As the snippet shows, I can't click the secondary menu, as it disappears. I'm sure there is a dumb solution I couldn't think of, but what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first instinct would be to use JavaScript but for this but there's a slick way to accomplish this with what are essentially operators in CSS...

Use the `:hover` pseudo-class on a parent element and look for the instance of the dropdown.

```
.nav:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Because you're selecting the parent element, it applies to both the dropdown and what you hover over to show it over so it's displayed whenever it's within those realms. Make more and they'll work just the same respective to their individual dropdowns.

https://jsfiddle.net/ksxk33w4/1/

Comment: It worked! I applied it to li and put all the dropdown menu in the parent li. Thank you very much !